# "Busy" progress dialog causes strange code processing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

Let me sum up the situation for you:

- I have a button (btnChooseEp), and when you press it an AlertDialog appears.
- When something is picked in the AlertDialog, three if statements must be evaluated.
- While they are being evaluated, a ProgressDialog appears. It indicates that the app is "busy".
- After the evaluation of these statements, the ProgressDialog must disappear.

My problem is described beneath the code.

The entire code block is shown here:

```
ProgressDialog getTracklistProgressDialog = null;
```

...

```
    Button btnChooseEp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChooseEp);
    btnChooseEp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {               
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GA.this);
            builder.setTitle(getText(R.string.chooseEpisode));
            builder.setItems(episodes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int pos)
                {                       
                    getTracklistProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GA.this, "Please wait...",
                            "Retrieving tracklist...", true);

                    new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {                       
                                String str1, epURL;

                                if(pos < 9)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo1);        
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);                 
                                }
                                else if(pos < 100)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo2);
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);
                                }
                                else if(pos >= 100)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo3);
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {}

                            // Remove progress dialog
                            getTracklistProgressDialog.dismiss();                               
                        }
                    }.start();                          
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Not sure if needed, but here is the code for the function setTracklist:

```
public void setTracklist(String string, TextView tv)
{
    try
    {
        tv.setText(getStringFromUrl(string));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

And the code for the function getStringFromUrl can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/xYt3FwaS

**Now, the problem:**
Back when I didn't implement the ProgressDialog thing (which I have from here, btw: http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_displaying_a_simple_progressdialog-t250.html), it worked fine - the setTracklist function retrieves a string from a text file on the internet, and sets the text to a TextView. Now, when I have added the ProgressDialog code, and put the original code into the try statement, only a very little part of the text file is added to the TextView - approximately 22-24 characters, not more. The "busy" ProgressDialog shows up just fine. It worked perfectly before; it was more than capable of loading more than 1300 characters into the TextView.
I don't know if it has anything to do with the thread - I have Googled a lot and found no answer.

So, how do I get it to load in all data instead of just a small part?

(By the way, I would love to be able to set the line "setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);" beneath all of the if statements, but then it says it can't resolve "epURL". Seems stupid to write the same line 3 times!)

**Updated 25/1 with current code:**

```
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
final Button btnChooseEp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChooseEp);
btnChooseEp.setEnabled(false);
btnChooseEp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{           
        public void onClick(View v)
        {               
            builder.setTitle(getText(R.string.chooseEpisode));
            builder.setItems(episodes2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int pos)
                {                       
                    replay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    replayWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    getTracklistProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GA.this, "Please wait...",
                            "Retrieving tracklist...", true);

                    new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {                       
                                String str1, epURL;

                                if(pos < 9)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.gaEpNo1);      
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist2(epURL, tracklist);                    
                                }
                                else if(pos < 100)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.gaEpNo2);
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist2(epURL, tracklist);
                                }
                                else if(pos >= 100)
                                {
                                    str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.gaEpNo3);
                                    epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                    setTracklist2(epURL, tracklist);
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {}

                            // Remove progress dialog
                            uiHandler.post(new Runnable()
                            { 
                                public void run()
                                { 
                                    getTracklistProgressDialog.dismiss();                                       
                                }
                            }
                            );                              
                        }
                    }.start();                          
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

public void setTracklist2(final String string, final TextView tv)
{
    try
    {
        uiHandler.post(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            tv.setText(getStringFromUrl(string));
                        }
                        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Notes: "replay" and "replayWeb" are just two TextView's. "btnChooseEp" is enabled when another button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting bizarre behavior because you are invoking a ui method on a non-ui thread.
    getTracklistProgressDialog.dismiss();
must be executed on a ui thread.  My guess is that it is crashing and your thread is crashing then leaving some of your resources in a bad state.  This would explain why you get a varying amount of characters.

I would try creating a final Handler in your onCreate method which would get bound to the uiThread.  In that thread, you can then call

```
uiHandler.post( 
 new Runnable() { 
  public void run(){ 
    getTracklistPRogressDialog.dismiss();
  }
 }
);
```

This is quick, so it may not be syntactically correct, check your ide.

This is the best i can get from what you've posted.  If you post more of the code I can try to run it to give you more help.

Update:

I think I found your problem:

The idea of having another thread is to do the long running work there, but what we have right now actually does the long running work on the ui thread, the opposite of our goal.  What we need to do is move the call to `getStringFromUrl(url)` from the setTracklist call up into the thread.  I would rewrite setTracklist as follows:

```
public void setTracklist(String tracklistContent, TextView tv)
{
    try
    {
      runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            tv.setText(tracklistContent);
          }
         });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Then in your inner onClick method, do this:

```
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, final int pos)
            {                       
                getTracklistProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GA.this, "Please wait...",
                        "Retrieving tracklist...", true);

                new Thread()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {                       
                            String str1, epURL;

                            if(pos < 9)
                            {
                                str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo1);        
                                epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                String tlContent = getStringFromUrl(epUrl);
                                setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);                 
                            }
                            else if(pos < 100)
                            {
                                str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo2);
                                epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                String tlContent = getStringFromUrl(epUrl);
                                setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);
                            }
                            else if(pos >= 100)
                            {
                                str1 = getResources().getString(R.string.epNo3);
                                epURL = String.format(str1, pos+1);
                                String tlContent = getStringFromUrl(epUrl);
                                setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {}

                        // Remove progress dialog
                        getTracklistProgressDialog.dismiss();                               
                    }
                }.start();                          
            }
```

I'm so, we make the call to the web service/url before we regain ui thread execution.  The long running internet retrieval runs on the bg thread and then the ui update happens on the ui thread.  Think this should help.

Comment: Never dealt with Handles before, but here's what I've done: Put "final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();" in the onCreate method (right after setContentView). Put your code instead of the single .dismiss() statement in my code. No errors in the IDE, but it makes no difference in the app I'm afraid. What more code do you think could help?

Comment: Can you run this in debug mode on the emulator from your workbench?  It should automatically break when there is an exception raised, which would tell us the line which is causing a problem.  I also see you're setting the text value of a ui element in setTracklist, so you should wrap that in the handler the same way you did the dismiss.  All ui element touches need to happen on the same thread

Comment: In fact, i'd wrap your setTracklist elements first, because you are swallowing all exceptions, my guess is that that is causing a Invocation exception which is getting eaten by your code.

Comment: If I put "setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);" down in the code for the uiHandler, it says that epURL cannot be resolved. (Actually the same thing written in the last 2 lines of my first post.) I didn't quite understand what you meant by "wrapping the setTracklist elements" in your last answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems it's working now. What I did: defined the string variable "epURL" in the top of the code: "static String epURL;" (above onCreate method). Deleted "setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);" from each if statement and put it down in the uiHandler thread instead. Not sure if that's the best way?

Comment: Updated answer with what I meant.

Comment: Thanks. However, it has the same visual effect as what I described in my last comment. I thought it worked properly, but I noticed that it doesn't. Here is what happens: I click on an item in the AlertDialog, the dialog disappears, but no progressbar shows UNTIL it has retrieved the file content from the internet, then disappears right after and the text is shown in the textview. So, the progressbar does not have the "busy" effect here.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but could you update your code to what you are now using.  I've reviewed it and can't see anything that looks like it would be producing the situations you describe.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, i did not see the method getStringFromUrl... i'm going to assume thats where you go out to the internet to do something.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick for your help, it works perfectly now! :) I wrote "setTracklist(tlContent, tracklist);" instead of "setTracklist(epURL, tracklist);", but that was what you meant of course.